# htaccess is inactive doesn't affect url anyway

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have website name "[www.hamargoth.com](http://hamargoth.com/)" I want to rewrite the URL because it blog based website and normal URL with Id doesn't look good and doesn't support SEO. I tried the sing htaccess file but it is not working. So please help if anyone can. To understand current URL please check website www.hamargoth.com

```
ReWriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Postdetail/([^/.]+)?$ /Postdetail.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What url are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: http://hamargoth.com/Postdetail.php?pid=94                                          
to                                                                 
http://hamargoth.com/Post/94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect /Postdetail.php?pid=123 to /Post/123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Postdetail.php\?pid=(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /Post/%1? [L,R]
#since /Post/123 doesn't exist we will rewrite the new uri to its original location
#rewrite /Post/123 to /Postdetail.php?pid=123
RewriteRule ^Post/(.+)/?$ /Postdetail.php?pid=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working But CSS is also not working, I also wanted to ask if urk is like "hamargoth.com/Post.php?scat=Raipur" and want to change "hamargoth.com/Raipur"  what changes in current code I should Make.

Comment: "hamargoth.com/Post.php?scat=Raipur" to "hamargoth.com/Category/Raipur" it is also working but unable to pass the variable so the query is going blank on that page. Url is working Fine